# c++ error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, graph

I have written this code for the graph.This code is compiling successfully but when I run it shows `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

This code is Printing adjacent of the graph using printGraph function.How to solve this error?

```
    class graph{
    public:
        std::vector< std::vector<int> > list;
        int n;
        graph(int n){
            this->n=n;
            list.resize(n);
        }
        void addEdge(int a,int b){
            list[a].push_back(b);
            list[b].push_back(a);
        }
        void printGraph(){
            std::vector< std::vector<int> >::const_iterator vertex;
            std::vector<int>::const_iterator adjacent;
            int i=0;
            for(vertex=list.begin();vertex != list.end() ; ++vertex )
            {
                std::cout<<"Adjacent of "<<i<" is : ";
            for(adjacent = vertex->begin();adjacent != vertex->end();++adjacent){
                std::cout<<*adjacent<<" ";
            }  
            i+=1;      
            std::cout<<"\n";
            }
                }
   };

main(){
    graph gh(5);
    gh.addEdge(1,2);
    gh.addEdge(1,3);
    gh.addEdge(2,4);
    gh.addEdge(2,5);
    gh.addEdge(3,5);
    gh.addEdge(4,5);
    gh.addEdge(4,6);
    gh.addEdge(5,6);
    gh.printGraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: what is debugger?

Comment: [A debugger is a software tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that allows you to control the execution of a program and inspect its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main you define `gh(5)` which allocates the vector of size 5 then you use your `addEdge` method with parameter `(5,6)` which tries to access `list[5]` but the five list entries are `list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],` and `list[4]`. So I guess `gh.addEdge(5,6)` gives the Segmentation fault as it is out of range of your vector.